# background thread behaving differently depending on when the method it's called

Tags: ios, multithreading, core-data, uisearchbar, nsfetchedresultscontroller

On a CoreDataTableViewController (that subclass done by the people from Stanford) I have a fetch from a sqlite database.

The fetch is very fast on the simulator and on the device, but to make it older-devices-friendly, I'd like to perform the fetch on the background and add a spinner while it's being done. So I added a prefetch method. The whole thing looks like this:

```
-(void)setupFetchedResultsController{

    NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:self.entity];

    request.propertiesToFetch=[NSArray arrayWithObject:self.attribute];
    request.resultType=NSDictionaryResultType;
    request.returnsDistinctResults=YES;

    NSPredicate *predicate1 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K != nil", self.attribute]; 
    NSPredicate *predicate2 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K != ''", self.attribute];
    NSPredicate *predicate3=  [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K contains[cd] %@", self.attribute, self.seachBar.text];

    NSArray *prepredicateArray;

    if ([self.seachBar.text length]) {
         prepredicateArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:predicate1, predicate2, predicate3,nil];

    }else {
         prepredicateArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:predicate1, predicate2,nil];

    }

    request.predicate=[NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:prepredicateArray];
    request.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:self.attribute ascending:YES ]];


    self.fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:request
                                                                        managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext
                                                                          sectionNameKeyPath:nil
                                                                                   cacheName:nil];


    [self performFetch];
}





-(void)prefetch{

    UIView *translucentView=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(110, 102, 100, 100)];
    [translucentView setCornerRadius:7.0];
    translucentView.backgroundColor=[UIColor blackColor];
    translucentView.alpha=0.65;

    UIActivityIndicatorView *spinner=[[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
    spinner.frame=CGRectMake(0, 31.5, 100, 37);
    [translucentView addSubview:spinner];

    [spinner startAnimating];

    [self.view addSubview:translucentView];


    dispatch_queue_t fetchQueue = dispatch_queue_create("fetch stuff", NULL);

    dispatch_async(fetchQueue, ^{

        [self setupFetchedResultsController];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            [translucentView removeFromSuperview];

        });

    });

    dispatch_release(fetchQueue);

}
```

The thing is that when I call the `prefetch` method from `viewWillAppear` everything is fine, but when I call it from a method called when editing the searchBar (the fetch dynamically shows the fetched results while typing on a searchBar) it gives the following error:

```
void _WebThreadLockFromAnyThread(bool), 0x6b9b730: Obtaining the web lock from a thread other than the main thread or the web thread. UIKit should not be called from a secondary thread.
```

It was my understanding that UI stuff should be performed on the main thread, but I fail to see where the error is.

Any pointers?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: I added an ios tag to the question.  Not sure if that's correct.

Comment: Have you actually tested the performance on an older device? Core Data's fetching is pretty fast, and you can set up the fetch request to limit number of records returned, faulting options, etc, so that will help quite a bit. Also, not so sure creating your `NSFetchedResultsController` on a background thread is such a good idea. Have you read Apple's documentation on Core Data and concurrency? That will be helpful, should you continue down that path (which you should only do as last resort with Core Data)

Comment: Yeah, I think you're rigth. I was just rewatching lesson #14 of the Stanford course and in the very first slide the instructor says: Core Data is not thread-safe. So, the problem must be here. One can perform it on a block though. But as you pointed out it might not be even necessary. Thanks for the remainder.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it might be caused by accessing the searchbar's text. I was having a similar warning on one of my background thread methods and I tracked the issue down to the searchbar's text method. I noticed you are doing that also.

If this is your case, an easy solution for the warning is to just get the searchbar's text while still on the main thread.

It does fix my issue, but I really want to know why the warning shows up. I've been trying to find something about this both in the web and Apple's documentation for a while, but no luck yet.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll have a look next time I deal with the issue (the update is already on the store). However I was looking deeply into the docs about core data and it is true that it is not thread-safe, so one has to be careful with it. An oficial work around is to perform the fetch within a block, I believe.

Comment: The warning doesn't come up because core-data isn't thread-safe. Using a block in a background thread wouldn't remove the warning, as it would still be done in background.

Comment: Core-data not being thread-safe means concurrent executions could result in unpredictable results. You could still do this in background without that warning, if you remove whatever it is that is accessing the UI interface from a background thread (I believe is the searchbar's text, as I pointed out). But it would be wise to have a way of making sure there's never more than one thread executing core-data logic, to prevent unpredictable results.